After processing the OAUTH2 credentials, something went wrong
As I'm trying to make things work this OAUTH2 for Twitter, based from here: https://joemayo.medium.com/using-oauth-2-0-with-linq-to-twitter-eac6d9035084
I did provide the CLIENT ID and CLIENT SECRET but below is what I'm encountering.

I am able to only reach here then when I clicked the BEGIN the Authorization process, I end up with something went wrong.:

Maybe you guys have a thorough tutorial on this.
The codes on OAUTH2 Controller:
  public async Task<ActionResult> BeginAsync()
  {
     string twitterCallbackUrl = Request.GetDisplayUrl().Replace("Begin", "Complete");

     var auth = new MvcOAuth2Authorizer
     {
      CredentialStore = new OAuth2SessionCredentialStore(HttpContext.Session)
      {
        ClientID = "CodeEXAMPLEPURPOSE",
        ClientSecret = "CodeEXAMPLEPURPOSE",
        Scopes = new List<string>
        {
            "tweet.read",
            "tweet.write",
            "tweet.moderate.write",
            "users.read",
            "follows.read",
            "follows.write",
            "offline.access",
            "space.read",
            "mute.read",
            "mute.write",
            "like.read",
            "like.write",
            "block.read",
            "block.write"
        },
        RedirectUri = twitterCallbackUrl,
      }
     };

     return await auth.BeginAuthorizeAsync("MyState");
   }

   public async Task<ActionResult> CompleteAsync()
  {
     var auth = new MvcOAuth2Authorizer
     {
         CredentialStore = new OAuth2SessionCredentialStore(HttpContext.Session)
      };

      Request.Query.TryGetValue("code", out StringValues code);
      Request.Query.TryGetValue("state", out StringValues state);

       await auth.CompleteAuthorizeAsync(code, state);

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
    }


You can check in the developer portal that the callback URL you set exactly matches the one you used in your code, and that you specified the correct scope when requesting authentication.
